# Java web hosting options available

Tags: java, jsp

I have implemented solutions for the clients who have internal servers, but never done any project that uses a java web hosting service(paid or otherwise).

I have to ensure the reliability, security and efficiency of the system.

So what are the java web hosting services available which meet the above criteria? Prefer an answer based on the personal experience, because I would like to know if there have been any bad experiences with java hosting services.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only partially ensure 'reliability, security and efficiency' when using a hosting provider (cloud), as you cannot influence all aspects. You must make sure your application is capable of supporting certain requirements (NFRs). Clearly define responsibilities. I voted to close as this question is (IMHO) far too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I never used it, but I think it's working... because it's google;-) Have a look at google's app engine or openshift. That's from red hat.

Both are in a small version free.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/

https://openshift.redhat.com/app/

Regards,

boskop